# CORS issue With Shopify Checkout UI extension while Fetch API + app proxy

Tags: proxy, cors, shopify, fetch-api

I am implementing a Shopify Checkout UI extension in our existing app. I am trying to fetch API, but I am getting a [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) error:

> Access to fetch at 'https://test.myshopify.com/apps/express-proxy/shoppers/' from origin **'https://cdn.shopify.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cores' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

I already use `cors()` on the backend, but still I am getting this.

```
import cors from "cors"; const corsOptions = { exposedHeaders: 'x-auth', origin: '*', } app.use(cors()); –
```

```
const sendOtpHandler = async () =>{
  await fetch(https://${shop.name}.myshopify.com/apps/express-proxy/shoppers, {
    method: 'GET', 
   headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
              'Accept': 'application/json', 
               'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 
               '*' }, }) 
       .then((response) => response.json()) .then((data) => { console.log('getOTP', data);
    }) .catch((error) => console.error(error)); }
```

Comment: You write: _I already use cors() on the backend_. How have you configured CORS. Give more details.

Comment: import cors from "cors"; const corsOptions = { exposedHeaders: 'x-auth', origin: '*', } app.use(cors());

Comment: Add the client code also.

Comment: const sendOtpHandler = async () =>{
    await fetch(`https://${shop.name}.myshopify.com/apps/express-proxy/shoppers`, {
      method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
        },
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        
        console.log('getOTP', data);
      })
      .catch((error) => console.error(error));
  }

Comment: Please edit your question with those new details.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to add below lines in the `shopify.ui.extension.toml` of your extension, which will allow you to use the fetch API:

```
[capabilities]
network_access = true
```